# How to check for the existence of unreadable files before passing it to a fastcgi backend?

Tags: nginx, file-permissions

I have several PHP sites which I want to separate in terms of permissions. Therefore I created a new user and set up a PHP pool for those users. Consider the below configuration:

- PHP-FPM is running as user `php`
- nginx is running as user `nginx`
- The webroot is `/srv/http`, accessible by both php and nginx.
- The file `/srv/http/index.php` is readable by php, but *not* readable by nginx.
- The file `fastcgi_stuff` contains basic fastcgi params for setting headers, setting the backend, etc. Assume that the webroot for static files and PHP files are the same.

The below nginx.conf contains the essentials of this configuration, it is placed in a `server` directive:

```
server_name example.com;
root /srv/http;

index index.php;
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_stuff;
}
```

If I request `http://example.com/` with the above configuration, the page is loaded as expected. For `http://example.com/does.not.exist`, I get a 404 as expected.

To prevent passing inexistent files to PHP-FPM, I tried adding one of the below lines:

```
    try_files $uri =404;
    if ( !-e $request_filename ){ return 404; }
```

Both do not work as advertised, it tries to *open* the files instead of checking for existence by doing `stat()` call. I confirmed this by checking the source code and running `strace` on a worker process.

This is one basic case I was having trouble with, another case is where I hide the extension and therefore put a `try_files $uri.php =404` in the location block. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx tries to open the file because I had `disable_symlinks on;`. The relevant source code is in core/ngx_open_file_cache.c, function `ngx_file_info_wrapper`. (called from `ngx_open_cached_file`, from `ngx_http_script_file_code`).

If `disable_symlinks` is set to `off`, nginx does a simple stat call (`ngx_file_info` is typedef'd to `stat` on *nix). When `disable_symlinks` is set to something else (e.g. `on`), it tries to open the file in a way that is safe against symlink races and then performs a `fstat()` call on the opened file descriptor. Since nginx **cannot** open the file for reading as it has no permissions for that, it fails.

The short-term solution is to **enable symlinks** again using `disable_symlinks off`, a long term solution is to modify the functions to traverse to the containing directory and then `fstatat()` the file in that directory. Remember to disable symlinks for directories that do not contain PHP scripts, but are writable by the PHP user.

---

As mentioned on http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,225152,234724#msg-234724, this behaviour is [documented](http://nginx.org/r/disable_symlinks):

> On systems that do not support opening directories for search only, the use of these parameters requires that worker processes have read permissions for all checked directories.

I have uploaded [a patch](http://lekensteyn.nl/files/0001-Do-not-require-read-permissions-for-try_files-if.patch) that allows you to restrict symlinks and still make `try_files` or `if` work. See also the linked thread above.